# Emscripten WebAssembly: Exporting Class "Import #13 module="GOT.func" error: module is not an object or function"

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, webassembly, emscripten

I've been toying with the usage of WebAssembly in a project as an importable function module (with hope to eventually use in a React/Electron app), so I've set myself up with Emscripten and got to work using C++.

No issues implementing functions, but I have been unsuccessful with classes. I want to be able to expose and instantiate a class in JS and call the methods on it, persisting until the "task" is complete.

Below is an [example from Emscripten's own website](https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/embind.html#classes), which builds but throws an error when trying to run (likely due to my build command and JS importing process)

The error message is `[TypeError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): Import #13 module="GOT.func" error: module is not an object or function]`.

Is what I'm trying to achieve sensible and possible?

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <emscripten/emscripten.h>
#include <emscripten/bind.h>

using namespace emscripten;

class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(int x, std::string y)
        : x(x), y(y)
    {
    }

    void incrementX()
    {
        ++x;
    }

    int getX() const { return x; }
    void setX(int x_) { x = x_; }

    static std::string getStringFromInstance(const MyClass &instance)
    {
        return instance.y;
    }

private:
    int x;
    std::string y;
};

// Binding code
EMSCRIPTEN_BINDINGS(my_class_example)
{
    class_<MyClass>("MyClass")
        .constructor<int, std::string>()
        .function("incrementX", &MyClass::incrementX)
        .property("x", &MyClass::getX, &MyClass::setX)
        .class_function("getStringFromInstance", &MyClass::getStringFromInstance);
};
```

```js
const util = require('util');
const fs = require('fs');
var source = fs.readFileSync('./dist/module.wasm');
const env = {
    memoryBase: 0,
    tableBase: 0,
    memory: new WebAssembly.Memory({
        initial: 256
    }),
    table: new WebAssembly.Table({
        initial: 0,
        element: 'anyfunc'
    }),
}



var typedArray = new Uint8Array(source);

WebAssembly.instantiate(typedArray, {
    env: env
}).then(result => {
    console.log('MODULE: ', result.instance.exports)

}).catch(e => {
    // error caught
    console.log(e);
});
```

```json
{
  "name": "wasm-js-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build-test": "rm -rf ./dist && mkdir ./dist && em++ ./src/module.cpp -O2 -s WASM=1 -s SIDE_MODULE=1 --no-entry --bind -o ./dist/module.wasm && node test.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want to use `-s SIDE_MODULE`.   Using `SIDE_MODULE` enables emscripten dynamic linking (PIC) ABI which you probably don't want.

Building with `--no-entry` and with an output file ending in `.wasm` should be enough to build something that is as sand-alone as possible.  However remember that emscripten's output is really designed to be run by emscripten-generated JS so you may run into complications trying to load it yourself like this.

Comment: Hi, thanks for a fast reply! Tried removing `-s SIDE_MODULE=1` and I am receiving error `[TypeError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): Import #13 module="wasi_snapshot_preview1" error: module is not an object or function]`

Comment: Now you are running up against the fact that you need to implement the APIs that the module depends on.   You can use wasm-objdump or wasm-dis to see what imports it requires.   You will then need to provide implementations of each of the imports.   Normally with emscirpten you build with `-o <something>.js` and emscripten will provide those for you.

Comment: When I started doing tutorials I started off having Emscripten output its JS file which I import via require(), but now I am trying to export a class I never see any reference to "MyClass" in the file at all. Though I can see strings in the .wasm file that correspond. I feel I am missing something

Comment: **PROGRESS UPDATE**: So I was able to build the class with command `em++ ./src/testing.cpp -s --no-entry --bind -o ./dist/testing.js` and run the methods through the JS file using `onRuntimeInitialized` event. I haven't actually seen this referenced in many places. Changes how I wanted to require() my WASM code, is there any way to avoid this?